# React - How to open only one modal in an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-modal

So I have just started learning react and for my for first little project I decided to make a simple UI using the Marvel API. I have an array that displays all marvel characters that begin with a certain letter, for example; a user inputs 'h' and then they are shown every character that begins with the letter h. When a users clicks a character a modal pops up and displays info about that specific character.

My problem is that when a user clicks on a picture to open the modal all of the modals for every character in the array are opened. I dont know how to make only the modal that is selected to open.

```
    render () {
var characters = _.map(this.state.characters, (character, i) => {
var pic = character.thumbnail.path
var picExt = character.thumbnail.extension
return (
  <div className="styleResults" key={i}>
    <li><h3>{character.name}</h3></li>
    <div>
      <img src={`${pic}/standard_fantastic.${picExt}`} 
alt={`${character.name}`} onClick={() => this.openModal()}/>
      <Modal isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen} onClose={() => 
      this.closeModal()} contentLabel="marvelModal">
          <div>
            <div><h1>{character.name}</h1></div>
            <div><img className="modalIm" src=
 {`${pic}/standard_fantastic.${character.thumbnail.extension}`} alt=
 {`${character.name}`}/></div>
            <div>{character.description}</div>
          </div>
       <p><button onClick={() => this.closeModal()}>Close</button></p>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  </div>
);
});
return (
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>Enter a Character's Name</h2>
        <input ref="charS" type="text"/>
        <button onClick={ (e) => { this.updateCharSearch(); } 
        }>Search</button>
      </div>
      <div className="CharAndComDiv">
        <h2>Enter a Comic's Name</h2>
        <input ref="comicSearch" type="text"/>
        <button onClick={ (e) => { this.updateComicSearch(); } 
         }>Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>{characters}</ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul>{comics}</ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
    openModal() {
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: true })
}

   closeModal() {
   this.setState({ isModalOpen: false })
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create a modal for each character - create one modal that can render any selected character.

For example, store `modalOpenIndex` which will store the index of the currently opened character or `-1` for a closed model. Then move the `<Modal` to be the last item of the render (not in the map function).

```
<Modal 
    isOpen={this.state.modalOpenIndex >= 0} 
    onClose={() => this.closeModal()} contentLabel="marvelModal">
```

Comment: I have moved the modal outside the function but now I cant access the var I have made inside the map function to insert into the modal.

Comment: @GANON: What do you mean? you don't need the var inside the map function. You have the currently opened character by using the `modalOpenIndex` state variable. `this.state.characters[modelOpenIndex]`

Comment: Because I have {character.name} {character.description} inside the modal which is outside of the map function where they are declared, I can no longer access them. They are not declared globally. I can't seem to use the same method of retrieving the name and description as I did before. for example {character.name}. outside of the map function I dont know how to access the parts of the characters array...

Comment: if you've replaced `isModalOpen` with `modelOpenIndex` (number, index of currently opened modal) like i said, then you can replace `character` with `this.state.characters[modelOpenIndex]`. If this doesn't make sense to you then you should read up on how arrays work. `modelOpenIndex` should be `-1` if the modal is closed, or a positive integer specifying which character is currently being displayed in the modal. if the integer is > -1 then you show the modal and render the character at the specified index.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I Finally figured it out!